# kotlin if (bar == null) vs. bar ?: run

Tags: kotlin

Here is sample

```
if (bar == null) {
    // do something
}
```

vs.

```
bar ?: run {
    // do something. 
}
```

1. which one is best practice?
2. what is mutating property?
3. first one dosen't work with mutating property?

Comment: IMO the second version is substantially less explicit about its intent.  It's broadly equivalent to the frowned-upon `cond ? whatever : methodWithSideEffects();` pattern in Java.

Comment: I'd use `bar?.let { }` over `bar ?: run { }`

Comment: You can do the second, but other than adding some cool cowboy-style to your code, does it have any advantage?

Comment: @hudsonb Thanks for comment. But I don't think `bar?.let { }` is equivalent to `bar ?: run { }`. the former wouldn't be executed `if (bar == null)`.

Comment: @kocka thx. I saw the first doesn't work with mutating property but the second do. I want to know that is really true. That is why I ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which one is best practice?

As pointed out by Oliver, the intent is most clear when using `if(bar == null)`. This is also the approach used in official Kotlin documentation under [Checking for null conditions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions).

Though I don't suggest it in this case, Kotlin allows you to do neat things like this:

```
inline fun whenNull(input: Any?, block: () -> Unit) {
    if(input == null) block()
}
```

Which would allow you to rewrite `if(bar == null)` as:

```
whenNull(bar) {
    // Do something
}
```

> what is mutating property?

It's a variable whose value can be changed. Basically, the variable is declared using `var` and not `val`.

> first one dosen't work with mutating property?

This isn't really relevant to your example because you are checking `if(bar == null)`.

What you are referring to is relevant if you were checking `if(bar != null)`. In this case, if `bar` is a `var`, Kotlin can't smart cast it a non-null type since within the body of the `if` the value of `bar` could change at any time. This means within the body of the `if` you'd have to make safe calls on `bar` (`?.`), or use `!!`.

You can work around this by doing the following:

```
val b = bar
if(b != null)
{
  // b has been smart cast to a non-null type
}
```

Kotlin is able to smart cast `b` to a non-null type within the body of the `if` because it is non-mutable (`val`).

Alternatively, you can use a safe call and `let`, which calls the specified function/block with `this` value as its argument and returns its result. Given the safe call, `this` is of course non-null.

```
bar?.let {
   // this is bar (non-null)
}
```